Can a general recursive function be defined by Pr(x)?
In the book Metamathematics of First-Order Arithmetic, I learned that a general recursive function can be defined by a $\Delta_1$-formula. I am curious about another matter: Since we have $Pr_T^\bullet (x)$that represents provability and a definition of a recursive function, perhaps we can discuss the finite sequence (arithmetic expression) of the supposed function expands into PA, and then find its corresponding value through provability.
For example, the exponentiation I define below:
Define a primitive recursive function:
$$
g(x) = \ulcorner 1 \urcorner \quad \text{(the code of 1)}
$$
$$
h(a, b, c) = \ulcorner (\urcorner\overparen{} \ulcorner a \urcorner\overparen{} \ulcorner * \urcorner\overparen{}  c \overparen{} \ulcorner )\urcorner
$$
$$
f(x, 0) = g(x) = \ulcorner 1 \urcorner
$$
$$
f(x, n+1) = h(x, n, f(x, n))
$$
Then there exists a formula $\varphi(x, y, z)$ such that $f(x, y) = z$ iff $\varphi(x, y, z)$. But here $z$ is just the code of a string of symbols, not the number as a result, so next define:
$$
\text{exp}(x, y) = (\text{min}\ z) (Pr_T^\bullet(\ulcorner (\urcorner\overparen{} f(x, y)\overparen{} \ulcorner = \urcorner\overparen{} \ulcorner z \urcorner\overparen{} \ulcorner )\urcorner ))
$$
It seems to define exponentiation, but this should be wrong. The problem should occur in the last definition, because $(\text{min}\ z)$ acts on a predicate rather than a function. If so, how can this error be corrected? Another reason might be that $\{x | Pr_T^\bullet (x)\}$ is $\Sigma_1$, but I am not sure.

You haven't said which theory $T$ you intend to use, but probably you have in mind something like PA. You are proposing to define exponentiation $x^y$ essentially as "the smallest $z$ for which $T$ can prove that $z=x*x*\cdots*x$, with $y$ factors."
This idea has problems and ultimately it won't be provably equivalent to exponentiation. One big issue is that it just doesn't work at all in models of $T$ in which $\text{Con}(T)$ fails. The reason is that in such a model, everything is provable, and so the least $z$ meeting that condition will be $z=0$, which is not the answer we want.
Because of this, your definition is not provably equivalent to exponentiation. And this issue is a serious obstacle in general to using provability in this way to define functions, which addresses your title question negatively.
Note also, however, that the proposal doesn't provide a computable means of computing exponentiation, since $\mu z\, \varphi(z)$ is not computable in general for $\Sigma_1$ assertions $\varphi$, which is your case. Basically, we can't computably determine if $z=0$ will be the right answer, since if $\text{Con}(T)$ fails it will be, but there is no computable means to determine this.

What does, however, work is to take for a given $x,y$  the minimal proof of a formula of the form $\phi(\ulcorner x\urcorner, \ulcorner y\urcorner,\ulcorner z\urcorner)$, where $\phi$ is a $\Sigma_1$-definition of exponentiation, and output $z$.

(Meanwhile, the larger issue is: why bother? We already have straightforward definitions of exponentiation that don't involve coding up the proof system. Just code the primitive recursive definition itself.)

Well, the argument really shows that the proof predicate can serve the role of Kleene's $T$ predicate, giving an alternative proof of Kleene's normal form. I'm not sure how useful is that.

I don't think it works correctly, since in a model of $\neg\text{Con}(T)$, once you're above the proof of a contradiction, then the smallest proof code won't necessarily be proving what you expect. So we won't be able to prove from $T$ that it works for the normal form.

The proof of contradiction is nonstandard, whereas the proof witnessing the actual value of the function is standard, and therefore smaller. This is basically the Rosser trick.

Yes, I know that, but my point is that because things will get messed up for infinite input, we won't be able to prove in PA, say, that the normal form theorem holds with your proposed $T$ predicate, that it can represent any computable function, since it wouldn't work properly at nonstandard values in some PA models. (But perhaps I've misunderstood what you were claiming.) Of course it gets the purely standard part correct for halting standard computation.

Yes, this gives a $T$-predicate in the meta-theory, and the meta-theory needs to be strong ebough to prove the consistency of the theory whose proof predicate we consider. This does not have to be PA; it may be something much weaker such as Q, in which case the meta-theory can be rather weak as well.

For a related fact, one way of proving that $I\Delta_0+\mathrm{EXP}$ has a truth predicate for $\Sigma_1$ sentences is to take the cut-free provability predicate for Q.

I understand your answer. But I have a few concerns about the discussion. If $\phi$ is a definition of exponentiation, then the $\ulcorner z\urcorner$ in $\phi(\ulcorner x\urcorner, \ulcorner y\urcorner, \ulcorner z\urcorner)$ should be the result of the codes of x and y, which may not decode to a specific number z. So does this means to replace $Pr_T^\bullet$ with $Pr_T^R$ (Rosser's proof predicate) to make the definition better in the standard part? In the non-standard part, my definition will encounter the same obstacles as the normal form theorem. Is my understanding correct?

@Stanleysun The thrust of my answer is that looking for proofs that $x^y=z$ won't work correctly as a definition in every model of PA. You cannot prove in PA that your definition agrees with the usual definition of $x^y$, and it doesn't matter whether you use the usual proof predicate or the Rosser variation. Meanwhile, if you use Emil's suggestion, then it will happen at least to get things right on the standard numbers. But to my way of thinking, this is not how we want to define exponentiation in PA, if it doesn't give the right answer for some nonstandard numbers.

I didn't understand Emil’s suggestion. What does the "minimal proof of a formula of the form $\varphi(\ulcorner x\urcorner, \ulcorner y\urcorner, \ulcorner z\urcorner)$" refer to? The subsequent discussion seems to be about finding a theory weaker than PA where such a definition is feasible and $Pr_T^R$ becomes its $T$-predicate. Is there really such a theory?

His proposal is to use the minimal proof, not the minimal value of $z$, but then extract $z$ from that proof. This fixes the problem that I had identified, at least for standard $x$ and $y$. But it doesn't work correctly for nonstandard $x$ and $y$, and so I still find it wrong-headed to use proofs at all in the way you suggest.

I understand, thank you, and Emil.
